# React Native table view not getting populated

Tags: listview, reactjs, native

I am trying to populate a listview but the data is not getting displayed. I think that the issue must be in the render method but I can't seem to figure out what is the cause.

The JSON response seems to be correct.

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ListView,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
var productArray = [];
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2) => r1.guid != r2.guid});
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
      isLoading:true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTheData(function(json){
    productArray = json;
    this.setState({
      datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
      isLoading:false
    });
    //console.log(this.state.datasource);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }.bind(this));

  }

  getTheData(callback) {
    var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkarmyIN/React-Native-DynamicListView/master/appledata.json";
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => callback(json))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
        console.log("row redered");
  return (
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#dddddd' style={{height:44}}>
        <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#000000'}} numberOfLines={1}>Test</Text>
        <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

  render() {
    var currentView = (this.state.isLoading)?<View/>:<ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} enableEmptySections={true}/>

    return(
      <View>
      {currentView}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

module.exports = Home;
```

Comment: Did you try removing `this.forceUpdate()`? And I also want to know whether the log `row rendered` was showed. Thx.

Comment: Yes I did try to force an update. No row render is not showing on the log.

Comment: I think `this.forceUpdate` is not necessary so remove it, and I want to know the value of `this.state.isLoading` before render, so can you log it before `return` in `render()` ?

Comment: It is showing as true and then false.